# Probability density function with a constant

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given an X case variable with probability density function
 where $$ n>3$$

[image: Function]

1. Find c - I did an Integral on it and did it equal to 1 and got that : $$c = n-1$$
2. Find the cumulative distribution function - now about here im not sure, as I did an Integral plugging c and integrated from 1 to infinity and got : $$-x^{1-n}$$  Is it possible to be negative?

Comment: Since $c=n-1$, the PDF is just $(n-1)x^{-n}$ on $x\ge1$.

Comment: You already have the probability density function; you just have to plug in the $c$ that you calculated. Perhaps you're looking for the cumulative distribution function?

Comment: yes exactly @joriki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n\leq1$ then $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-n}dx=+\infty$ and in these cases $f(x)$ is not a PDF.

If $n>1$ and $c=n-1$ then function $f$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto (n-1)x^{-n}$ if $x>1$ and $x\mapsto 0$ otherwise.

This function is non-negative and moreover is a PDF.

So your outcome for $c$ is correct, but its calculation also reveals the condition $n>1$.

The CDF is found as:$$F(x)=\int^x_{-\infty}f(y)dy$$

Here we discern the cases $x<1$ and $x\geq1$. The integrand is $0$ on $(-\infty,1]$ so in the first case we get $F(x)=0$.

In the second case we get:$$F(x)=\int^x_{-\infty}f(y)dy=(n-1)\int^x_{1}y^{-n}dy=\left(n-1\right)\left[\frac{y^{1-n}}{1-n}\right]_{1}^{x}=1-x^{1-n}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge1$ the CDF is $\int_1^x(n-1)t^{-n}dt=[-t^{1-n}]_1^x=1-x^{1-n}$, whereas for $x<1$ it's $0$.